# Bootstrap 3 - place 4 divs by 25% and one more div below properly

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm curious what's the proper code for placing 4 divs by 25% and more div below properly?
I'm trying

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">1</div>
</div>
<div class="row">below</div>
```

However I'm not sure if this is correct.
Also, I see margins appear there:
[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/3894/)

Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: Your Fiddle differs from the code you post here ... Also why are U unsure that isn't correct ... it's fine

Comment: Do you mean like this? - http://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/3907/

Comment: @Daniel Pinzon what exaclty? Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either use one full-width column in your second row

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">1</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-12">below</div>
</div>
```

… or don't use the `row` class at all for your second row:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-3">1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">1</div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">1</div>
</div>
<div>below</div>
```